# how to turn this piece of code inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have started to learn JavaScript, and I was trying to make an animation of a loading bar, but I do not know how to make it repeat the function after the bar reaches to the end, I thought maybe with a loop I can get the outcome I wanted, but I am still learning about loops, I have tried different methods, and changing the whole code, and nothing worked.

```
const progressBar1 = document.getElementsByClassName
('progress-bar1')[0]
setInterval(() => {
  const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(progressBar1)
  const width = parseFloat(computedStyle.getPropertyValue
    ('--width')) || 0
  progressBar1.style.setProperty('--width', width + .1)
},5)
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your loops is infinite, it never stops. So your already did half the job, now all you need is get the maximum value for the width, once it's reached, reset width to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a loop by using `setInterval` to call this set of code each 5ms.

One way you could have this continue to loop back the growth progress is by setting a max-width. I'm not sure if there is a parent container you could query for width or if you wanted to set a constant, but just check each time the width is greater than max, reset back to 0 and grow again.

```js
const progressBar1 = document.getElementsByClassName
('progress-bar1')[0];
const widthMax = 300;

setInterval(() => {
  const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(progressBar1);
  const widthCurrent = parseFloat(computedStyle.getPropertyValue
    ('--width')) || 0;

  const width = widthCurrent > widthMax ? 0 : widthCurrent;
  progressBar1.style.setProperty('--width', width + .1);
}, 5);
```